# place to put head code in custom theme

Tags: theme

I need to put this in the head section

BUT only for the CMS pages that I have running under a custom theme.- and only in the blank layout if possible
been through a few locations and I am unsure where to put. I tried header.phtl in the theme folder but that didnt seem to work.

Hope to help thanks

Comment: sorry i dont understand how to make the code appear in forum.

Comment: paste your code in your question and then click/drag to highlight it then click the icon {} this will allow code to be pasted or you can highlight it and hold the control key down and push the letter 'k'

Answer (score 1):

**First**
Create your template file in **app/design/frontend/yourthemepath/template/page**

**Then**
Put this in the **Custom Layout Update XML** section of your CMS Page

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/template" name="yourtheme_yourname" template="page/yourfile.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

This allows you to choose what theme/layout and even dates to apply this update.

Comment: Thank you - but I have many CMS pages I want to put into and I prefer to not have to copy that into every page. Is there a better way please

Comment: Create file local.xml in app/design/frontend/yourtheme/layout and put the above xml there to apply it to all pages in that theme.

Comment: I am not confident I can do this correctly. I just want to add meta tags to the head. If I make blank local.xml in themes folder , why would i need to state the block above, cant i just add the tags. When I am confused I wont try ( failsafe ) :)

Comment: The XML calls the code in yourfile.phtml into the head block. You will need to put the meta tags in yourfile.phtml